# Fetch contacts and profile picture using dotnetopenauth

Tags: .net, dotnetopenauth

I can fetch First name, Last name and email from google using dotnetopenauth by using WellKnownAttributes.Name.First and so on. I couldn't find a well known attribute that can fetch Profile picture. How cna I retrieve that?

Also, can I use dotnetopenauth to retrieve contacts from google?

Answer (score 0):

There are samples that ship with DotNetOpenAuth that demonstrate downloading Google Contacts (OAuthConsumer and OAuthConsumerWpf).

Retrieving a profile picture is not in the samples.  You'll have to look up the GData API to see if that's offered via OAuth or some other means.